How to solve simple second order ODE with RHS $x / \sigma^2$
I have the following Hamiltonian systems for $i=1, \ldots, d$ and $\sigma_i > 0$
$$
\begin{align}
    \frac{d}{dt} x_i &= v_i \\ 
    \frac{d}{dt} v_i &= \frac{x_i}{\sigma_i^2}
\end{align}
$$
What is the solution of this system?

Attempted Solution
This system is equivalent to
$$
\frac{d^2}{dt^2}x_i(t) = \frac{x_i}{\sigma_i^2}
$$

Have you never solved a linear ODE with constant coefficients?

By inspection, it may be seen that both
$$
x_i(t)=e^{t/\sigma_i},\quad
x_i(t)=e^{-t/\sigma_i}
$$
are solutions to the equation. Hence the general solution is a linear combination of the form
$$
x_i(t)=c_{1i}\,e^{-t/\sigma_i} + c_{2i}\,e^{t/\sigma_i}
$$
where the values of $\{c_{1i},c_{2i}\}$ are to be determined from the $2d$ initial conditions. Equations like this occur frequently in physical applications (often with a minus sign in your second Hamilton equation of motion), and are filed under "simple harmonic oscillator" equations.
